# Is it possible to get an int from Range.Value in VSTO?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, int

I have a VSTO addin and I'm reading data from an Excel worksheet.

It seems that almost all numeric data is read as a `double`. Is it ever possible to get an `int` value from `Range.Value`?

Here is some code to demonstrate what I mean.

```
Worksheet w = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
var value = ((Range)w.Cells[1, 1]).Value;
bool isInt = value is int;
bool isDouble = value is double;
```

No matter which format I use in worksheet Sheet1, cell A1, `isInt` always comes back false.

Is there some format I should be using to get `int`? I thought maybe `General` or `0` would work, but it seems not.

Comment: I don't think you'd ever get an int - Excel never stores numbers as an int internally, always a double.

Comment: @Govert Okay, that's what I suspected but I wanted confirmation. If you post an answer (preferably with a source about that Excel tidbit) I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlrangevaluedatatype.aspx) when you call `var value = ((Range)w.Cells[1,1]).Value` the `Value` type is derived from the value type from the Worksheet. So it would seem that your Excel worksheet has the values formatted as `doubles`, not `int`s. There is no "integer" formatting for Excel that will translate to C#, the best bet would be to cast the value as an `integer` when you read it in. The `Value` type comes in whatever format it was within the Excel worksheet.

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113) shows how Excel deals with double precision floating point values.

Comment: Right, but my question is essentially, "What worksheet format will give me `int`?" General, Number with no decimals, Text, Accounting all give me doubles. Am I missing something or is there no such format?

Comment: Ah, doing a little research shows that it looks like the numbers are always stored as doubles in Excel. You can make a custom format that _looks_ like an int in the worksheet, but when you query the values from C# they will be returned as doubles. If you do this though you can guarantee that the values (as doubles) will **really** be integers, then you can just cast as int.

Comment: Got it. Can you provide the source about only doubles being stored in Excel?

Comment: @root45 I couldn't find a source that says that specifically, I edited my answer with one that talks about how they are stored however, the implication is there. Really its not "doubles" but rather Excel has what it calls just "Number" that stores the number in a double precision floating point value.

Answer (score 2):

Numeric values returned by Range.Value are doubles (possibly becuase they are all stored as doubles in Excel, a number looking like an integer or not is the result of formatting)

The only ints that I have seen coming through GetValue are the ErrorCodes for errors

**e.g.**

- DIV/0! is an Int32 with a value of -2146826281

Answer (score 1):

Govert is correct in saying that Excel never stores numbers as an integers.

Excel stores numeric values as `Double Precision Floating Point` numbers, or as you know `Doubles` for short.

`Doubles` are 8-byte variables that can store numbers accurate to approximately 15 decimal places.

**EDIT**:

Since you are looking for a link, see this

Link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure all numbers are doubles in Excel.  For example the following VBA code sets a cell value to a long integer (Int32), then reads it back.

```
Dim n As Long
n = 123
Range("A1").Value = n
Debug.Print VarType(n)

Dim v As Variant
v = Range("A1").Value
Debug.Print VarType(v)
```

- Input is VarType(n) = 3 = vbLong (Int32)
- Output is VarType(v) = 5 = vbDouble